# GDL Antlr grammar

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4, datalog

I need a parser for Game Description Language (GDL) in Java

For this I am currently trying to use ANTLR4.

my current grammar given in the following does seem to be not correct or at least the generated parser does not recognize a game description which i will also provide below.

The ANTLR4-Grammar:

```
grammar GDL;

description :  (gdlRule | sentence)+ ;

gdlRule : '(' SP? '<=' SP? sentence (SP literal)* SP? ')';

sentence : propLit | ( '(' relLit ')' );

literal : ( '(' SP? (orLit | notLit | distinctLit | relLit) SP? ')' ) 
| ( '('  (orLit | notLit | distinctLit | relLit) ')' ) 
| propLit;
notLit : 'not' SP literal | '~' literal;
orLit : 'or' SP literal* ;
distinctLit : 'distinct' SP term SP term;
propLit : constant;
relLit : constant (SP term)+;

term : ( '(' funcTerm ')' ) | varTerm | constTerm;
funcTerm : constant (SP term)*;
varTerm : '?' constant;
constTerm : constant;


constant : ident | number;
/* ident is any string of letters, digits, and underscores */
ident: ID;
number: NR;
NR : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]* ;
SP : ' '+;

COMMENT : ';'[A-Za-z0-9; \r\t]*'\n' -> skip;
WS : [ ;\t\r\n]+ -> skip
;
```

The game description given in GDL:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;; Tictictoe
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (role white)
  (role black)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (init (cell 1 1 b))
  (init (cell 1 2 b))
  (init (cell 1 3 b))
  (init (cell 2 1 b))
  (init (cell 2 2 b))
  (init (cell 2 3 b))
  (init (cell 3 1 b))
  (init (cell 3 2 b))
  (init (cell 3 3 b))
  (init (step 1))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (<= (next (cell ?j ?k x))
      (true (cell ?j ?k b))
      (does white (mark ?j ?k))
      (does black (mark ?m ?n))
      (or (distinct ?j ?m) (distinct ?k ?n)))

  (<= (next (cell ?m ?n o))
      (true (cell ?m ?n b))
      (does white (mark ?j ?k))
      (does black (mark ?m ?n))
      (or (distinct ?j ?m) (distinct ?k ?n)))

  (<= (next (cell ?m ?n b))
      (true (cell ?m ?n b))
      (does white (mark ?m ?n))
      (does black (mark ?m ?n)))

  (<= (next (cell ?p ?q b))
      (true (cell ?p ?q b))
      (does white (mark ?j ?k))
      (does black (mark ?m ?n))
      (or (distinct ?j ?p) (distinct ?k ?q))
      (or (distinct ?m ?p) (distinct ?n ?q)))

  (<= (next (cell ?m ?n ?w))
      (true (cell ?m ?n ?w))
      (distinct ?w b))


  (<= (next (step ?y))
      (true (step ?x))
      (succ ?x ?y))


  (succ 1 2)
  (succ 2 3)
  (succ 3 4)
  (succ 4 5)
  (succ 5 6)
  (succ 6 7)


  (<= (row ?m ?x)
      (true (cell ?m 1 ?x))
      (true (cell ?m 2 ?x))
      (true (cell ?m 3 ?x)))

  (<= (column ?n ?x)
      (true (cell 1 ?n ?x))
      (true (cell 2 ?n ?x))
      (true (cell 3 ?n ?x)))

  (<= (diagonal ?x)
      (true (cell 1 1 ?x))
      (true (cell 2 2 ?x))
      (true (cell 3 3 ?x)))

  (<= (diagonal ?x)
      (true (cell 1 3 ?x))
      (true (cell 2 2 ?x))
      (true (cell 3 1 ?x)))

  (<= (line ?x) (row ?m ?x))
  (<= (line ?x) (column ?m ?x))
  (<= (line ?x) (diagonal ?x))


  (<= nolinex
      (not (line x)))
  (<= nolineo
      (not (line o)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (<= (legal white (mark ?x ?y))
      (true (cell ?x ?y b)))

  (<= (legal black (mark ?x ?y))
      (true (cell ?x ?y b)))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (<= (goal white 50)
      (line x)
      (line o))

  (<= (goal white 100)
      (line x)
      nolineo)

  (<= (goal white 0)
      nolinex
      (line o))

  (<= (goal white 50)
      nolinex
      nolineo)

  (<= (goal black 50)
      (line x)
      (line o))

  (<= (goal black 100)
      nolinex
      (line o))

  (<= (goal black 0)
      (line x)
      nolineo)

  (<= (goal black 50)
      nolinex
      nolineo)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

  (<= terminal
      (true (step 7)))

  (<= terminal
      (line x))

  (<= terminal
      (line o))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

The error output of the generated parser:

```
line 24:6 mismatched input '(' expecting {')', SP}
line 27:7 no viable alternative at input '(or'
```

I don't know what i have to change or how to get a correct grammar

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(At least) 3 things are incorrect:

- you include `;` in your `WS` rule and its the start of your `COMMENT`
- your `COMMENT` rule says it needs to end with a line break. However, line breaks are already included in the `WS` rule, and it would disallow comments that end with `EOF` (without a line break)
- `SP` is not needed: spaces need to be skipped and not included in your parser rules

Try something like this instead:

```
grammar GDL;

description :  (gdlRule | sentence)+ ;

gdlRule : '(' '<=' sentence literal* ')';

sentence : propLit | ( '(' relLit ')' );

literal 
 : ( '(' (orLit | notLit | distinctLit | relLit) ')' )
 | ( '('  (orLit | notLit | distinctLit | relLit) ')' )
 | propLit
 ;

notLit : 'not' literal | '~' literal;
orLit : 'or' literal* ;
distinctLit : 'distinct' term term;
propLit : constant;
relLit : constant (term)+;
term : ( '(' funcTerm ')' ) | varTerm | constTerm;
funcTerm : constant (term)*;
varTerm : '?' constant;
constTerm : constant;
constant : ident | number;
ident: ID;
number: NR;

NR : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
COMMENT : ';'[A-Za-z0-9; \r\t]* -> skip;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This seems to work even better than the suggestion by @rici there is no error output from the generated parser and the parse tree for the description looks alright at a quick overview

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your handling of whitespace.

You have two rules, one of which creates a token:

```
SP : ' '+;
```

and the other one which simply ignores the whitespace:

```
WS : [ ;\t\r\n]+ -> skip
```

If the whitespace starts with a space character, the first rule will apply and you will get a `SP` token. If the whitespace starts with a newline or some other character listed in the `WS` rule, the entire run of whitespace will be ignored.

Since your grammar insists on `SP` tokens at certain points, the ignored whitespace will cause a syntax error.

There is no reason that I can see to complicate your grammar with explicit whitespace. I would get rid of `SP`, remove all references to it in your grammar, and just let `WS` ignore whitespace.

I would also remove the semicolon from `WS` to avoid interactions with `COMMENT`. [Note 1] And I would simplify `COMMENT` so that it just ignores frim a semicolon to the end of the line, rather than gaving a list of valid comment characters. (What if you want to put a comma or a * in a comment?)

---

#### Notes

1. You would see this problem if there were a newline at the beginning of the file, with the row of semicolons at line 2. Then `COMMENT` does not match at the first character, but `WS` does. `WS` will then match (and ignore) the newline, the row of semicolons, the next newline, the semicolons at the beginning of the next line, and the following space, leaving `Tictictoe` to be scanned as an `ID`, which will cause a parse error.

   You would also see it if any other comment were something other than a row of semicolons. These are currently being scanned as `WS`, starring with the newline before the comment. That happens to be ok, since the comment only includes semicolons. But any other non-whitespace character would terminate the `WS` and then be unexpectedly parsed as program text.

Comment: I removed all references to `SP` and changed `COMMENT` and `WS` as follows:

`COMMENT : ';' * '\n' -> skip;
WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
   ;`

now the generated parser still fails to completely ignore comments, but the actual code seems to be recognized just fine (at least there are no parser errors about it)

`line 1:0 token recognition error at: ';;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;\r'
line 2:0 token recognition error at: ';;; '`

Comment: @S.Moenig: What I meant for the comment rule was something that matches any character, not just semicolons. Eg. `COMMENT : ';' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n' -> skip ;` (adapted from the [Antlr4 docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements))